# Most efficient way to create a table from 15 thousand files (from Storage to BQ)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I tried to use Google BQ Api and Google Storage API (I store all files there) just looping over all files and append new rows to the table during every iteration but I reached quota limit for appending to a table.

What would be the most efficient way? I thought about creating separate table for each file and than union them in BQ and save as new table, but I thought there could be a limit for amount of wildcard tables in query. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you used Mysql or Mariadb, you could use batch insert.

Comment: Which quota you hit?

Comment: "google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
"

Comment: are you using streaming insert for each row? or batched with the 10MB payload limit? Also why you are not using load file?

Comment: @Pentium10 I'm using load_table_from_uri function.

Comment: reduce the number of files by concatenating  and you should not have a problem with the limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest in a nutshell using [BQ load file mechanism from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage). This should be an uncompressed CSV, JSON, Avro or other support file format up to 5TB individual file size. You can upload in a load job up to 15TB that means three five tera files at most.

Google Cloud Storage supports a nifty feature called “compose”: it lets you compose a blob out of up to 32 source blobs. You can do this from the command line by doing:

```
gsutil compose \
  gs://${BUCKET}/somedir/csv/train* \
  gs://${BUCKET}/somedir/csv/full_training_data.csv
```

please note only 32 files can be used right now, so you need to do in iteration if you want to create larger but fewer files from those 15k.

Please be aware that there is daily 1000 load jobs limit per table, you can create multiple tables then merge them. Also 50k load job limit per project.

Each job operation (query or load) can affect a maximum of 2,000 partitions. You are limited to a total of 5,000 partition modifications per day for a partitioned table. More limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas).